# How can I combine information from 4 different tables in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a to write an SQL query to list the names and total spend of customers who made more 
than one order. The following lists all the relevant information but I'm struggling to see how to move forward with this.

```
SELECT l.quantity, o.orderID, i.itemID, o.custID, i.unitcost, c.familyname
FROM lineitems l, orders o, items i, customers c
WHERE l.itemID = i.itemID
AND c.custID = o.custID
AND o.orderID = l.orderID
ORDER BY o.custID
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?!

Comment: The sum() and count() functions will help you with this.  Then you'll need a having clause.  Given that this sounds like a schoolwork question, I suggest consulting your textbook for the things I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select customerId, Sum(i.quantity*i.unitCost)
From lineitems I
   join orders o on o.orderID = i.orderID
where Exists(Select * From orders
             where customerId = o.customerId
             having count(*) > 1)
group by customerId
```

or, with name instead of just customerId

```
Select c.familyname, Sum(i.quantity*i.unitCost)
From lineitems I
   join orders o on o.orderID = i.orderID
   join customers c on c.customerId = o.customerId
where Exists(Select * From orders
             where customerId = o.customerId
             having count(*) > 1)
group by c.familyname
```